# QGIS 3.22 UI theme > layer panel > increase line spacing?

Tags: qgis-3, gui

I'm using a tablet to enter some data outdoor, and QGIS was the most efficient way to do it (Roam was not compatible with the latest version of QGIS, QField not for Windows). To make it more user friendly I increased the size of icons and fonts in the options, and I'd like to know if there is a way to increase line spacing between the layers listed in the layer panel? Sometimes even the pen/stylus is not precise enough and I click or check the wrong line.

I already added a new UI theme in Options > General > Application, new folder in /project_templates/ with a `style.qss` file...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following lines to `style.qss`:

```css
QTableView::item,
QListView::item,
QTreeView::item
{
    padding: 3ex;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about "ex" units, but apparently more standard units works fine too. Thanks, greatly appreciated !